# JavaScript multiple checkboxes - delimited list - store and parse

Tags: javascript, database, checkbox, field

I was wondering if anybody can help

I'm  new and don't know any  Javascript.
I need help for my caspio app.

**The code below works** I just need to get the second part
I got the first part of storing the values of checked checkboxes in a database field as a comma de-limited list.

Now I need to read the comma de-limited list from the database and update the checkboxes accordingly.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function concatenate()
{
var Resultfieldname = "CheckboxChoices";
var firstVirtual = 1;
var lastVirtual = 3;
var ResultString = "";
var virtualFieldName = "";

for (i=firstVirtual ;i<=lastVirtual; i++)
{
virtualFieldName = "cbParamVirtual"+i;
if (document.getElementById(virtualFieldName).checked) ResultString = ResultString + "," + document.getElementById(virtualFieldName).value;
}
Resultfieldname = "EditRecord"+Resultfieldname;
if (ResultString.length>0) ResultString = ResultString.substr(1);
document.getElementById(Resultfieldname ).value = ResultString;
}
document.getElementById("caspioform").onsubmit=concatenate;
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: It seems like if you have an array, you could do `var listString = list.join();` and then to break it apart do something like: `var list = listString.split(',');`